# "Call me right after the interview and tell me how it went": why "went" when talking about the future?

Tags: tense

In a conversation

> Prepare for a Job Interview (2)
>
> I'm going to get there early and make sure I have my best outfit all washed and ironed way ahead of time.
>   If I wait for the last minute, I know I'll panic!
>
> Yeah, preparation is key. Remember to call the interviewer by their name.
>   People like to hear their name spoken out loud.
>   But don't over-do it. OK... So what are you planning on wearing next Tuesday?
>
> Well, I want to look good, but I don't want to look too stuffy.
>   I was thinking about nice jeans and a sport coat.
>
> Ummm... I'd recommend erring on the conservative side when it comes to clothes.
>   I read somewhere that fifty-five percent of another person's perception of you is based on how you look.
>   I'd say go with a suit and tie.
>
> Fifty-five percent huh? Then I guess it's better to be over-dressed than under-dressed.
>
> Yeah. I'd say a dark suit with a conservative tie.
>   But the one main thing that I can't stress enough is confidence.
>   If you need a clarification on something, speak up and ask... But don't turn into a blabbermouth.
>
> Do you think I should tell him how terrible it is working at Shimomatsu Publishing?
>   I bet he'd get a kick out of that!
>
> Actually, when I interview people, I hate it when they badmouth previous employers.
>   I think it's bad form and I also think "Is this what you're going to do to me one day?"
>
> Good point. Peter, you are a true friend and I value your input.
>
> **Call me right after the interview and tell me how it *went*, OK?**
>
> Absolutely.

(https://www.shanbay.com/speak/courses/lcnsc

tip: you can listen to it)

---

up 1: how about "*tell me how it **will have gone***"?

up 2: Since "*went*" is OK, how about "*tell me how it **has gone***"?

Comment: In future you'll be talking about the past.

Comment: Call me at lunch-time tomorrow and tell me what you _________ for breakfast.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo How about "what you *will have eaten* for breakfast"?

Comment: *will have eaten* is a prediction. *By this time tomorrow I will have spent three hours on the beach under a palm tree.* You cannot predict something after-the-fact. So, tomorrow, at lunch-time, I cannot predict what I ate for breakfast earlier in the day.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So "*tell me what you **have eaten** for breakfast*" is also right?

Comment: *Call me tomorrow and  tell me what you **have eaten** for breakfast* is grammatical. We can envision the speaker as imagining himself engaged in a real-time conversation tomorrow after breakfast.  It is a kind of imaginatively relocated present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *request* for you to call is being made in the present (they are asking you *now*), and they are asking you to do something in the future (call them) at a specific time (after the interview). When that condition is met, the interview will have already taken place and be in the *past*, so it is quite correct that they ask you to tell them *how the interview went*.

Comment: Similarly, if you were going to watch a play, I might say, "Call me during the intermission and tell me **how it's going**" (present tense, because the play is not yet over).

Comment: @J.R. How about "Call me during the intermission and tell me **how it will have been going**"?

Comment: @ZhangJian I don't think there's anything really wrong with that purely in terms of its syntactic construction—but almost nobody would ever *say* it that way (and they'd be looked at strangely if they did.). My immediate response at reading it is, "No, that's totally wrong!" But I think it may be an idiomatic response. It's simply not how any native speaker would phrase it.

Comment: @ZhangJian - Egads, no! No one talks like that. Besides, in this situation, it’s the phone call that will be in the future. So, we might ask: _**Will you call me** during the intermission and let me know how it’s going?_